# Scheduling Algorithm Goal is to Fix Max Number of Appointments

Tags: algorithms

First post.  Hi everyone.

I’m trying to develop an algorithm to later code that schedules appointments in a way such that the number of hours occupied by the appointments in a given day is maximized.

Appointments can be an hour or half hour long and all appointments should have a 15 minute buffer between them.

I’m getting stumped by the complexity of trying to come up with rules for this.

It’s currently being done by humans.

Someone texts, says they want a half hour or full hour, specifies a time that works best for them and they are fit into the schedule like a puzzle by a human being.

Preference is given to fitting the most appointments per day into a given 8 hour day.  Hour appointments are preferred but half hour is just fine.

The texters have times that work for them and a daily schedule is built up by hand in a very qualitative way.

I’m trying to automate this and it’s hard. Really hard.

There are cases where the wrong time appointment could be booked and it would eat up 2 hours of time.  For example:

Say you have 1pm to 3pm open without appointments.  Then say you have 4pm to 6pm open. A pair of 2 hour time slots. Ideally, you would want to fit a full hour and a half hour into each of those time slots.  However, if someone books their own half hour appointment at 1:45, , through the new self booking system, it makes it such that you can’t book any other appointments except the poorly placed 1:45 half hour in the entire 2 hour open period!  (Remember there is a 15 min buffer between each appointment). Now imagine someone does the same thing again booking 4:45 also.  You now have only 2 half hours taking up 4 hours of the day.  Bad!

The human mind just fits these all in as best it can and easily optimizes for the maximum amount of booked appointment time in a day. I’m really struggling to develop algorithms to do the same.  Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: One additional point.  The texting with a human is asynchronous.  The human scheduler can simply not respond for 5 minutes and wait to see what the best combination of requests is, booking 3 appointments in nicely based on a set of incoming requests. 

The computer can’t do this because someone working through a UI expects to see the available appointments then immediately get the appointment they choose.

Comment: You can solve this with things like MIPs and CSPs, but the real difficulty is UI and this isn't a great forum to discuss that.

Comment: So I have some ideas but I want to ask some clarifying questions first. So suppose someone wants to schedule an hour long appointment. Do they tell you what time works for them for just one day or for every day in the week and you guys figure out how soon you can squeeze them in? Do you schedule appointments as you get requests for them or do you have a list of appointments and you schedule them as a batch to hopefully optimize things better?

Comment: I’m trying to understand how much flexibility you actually have for choosing when to schedule someone’s appointment. If they desire the appointment at a certain time, seems the only thing you can change is the day they come in for the appointment, but not sure if you can assume that time works each day